# Find field existance in more than one group of fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with columns:

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|Column5
A,B,1,2,a
A,B,3,4,b
C,D,1,2,a
```

I need to check if the field group `column1|column2` has more than one combinations on the fields `column3|column4`

Example:

```
A,B 2
```

(Since for A,B combination, I have two combinations of column3|column4 i.e. 1,2 and 3,4)

```
C,D 1
```

Comment: Please define what is a *combination*. For you, is (1,2) the same combination as (2,1) ?

Comment: group by these two columns and take the count of them.

Comment: column3|column4 is my combination and so (1,2) is my combanation in this example.

Comment: This is for Oracle database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you would just do:

```
select col1, col2, count(*)
from table t
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1;
```

You make it sound like you want *distinct* values in columns 3 and 4.  Some databases support:

```
select col1, col2, count(distinct col3, col4)
from table t
group by col1, col2
having count(distinct col3, col4) > 1;
```

In other databases, it is just easiest to concatenate the values:

```
select col1, col2, count(distinct concat(col3, ':', col4))
from table t
group by col1, col2
having count(distinct concat(col3, ':', col4)) > 1;
```

Note:  although the `concat()` function is standard, it is not (yet) supported by all databases.

Comment: I used a distinct(col3, col4) and it worked like a charm. Thanks Guys.

Comment: `distinct()` as a function is not an ANSI SQL and you should not use it. You may consider the `concat()` function as shown in the above answer but then also you will have issue (see @dasblinkenlight 's comment in my answer)

Comment: Oops. I meant select col1, col2, count(distinct col3, col4) from table t group by col1, col2 worked for me. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Get the distinct count of the column3 and column4 combination like below

```
select column1, column2, count (distinct column3 || '-' || column4)
from table
group by column1, column2
having  count (distinct column3 || '-' || column4) > 1;
```

`||` is the concatenation operator for Oracle. In other databases you will have other concatenation operators. E.g. `concat`. The delimiter `-` will ensure the pairs like 12, 3 and 1, 23 do not produce same combination.

Comment: Yes - you are right! Thanks. Updated the answer by placing a delimiter in between.